# Class 'AppHelper' not found in Laravel

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 project, I am trying to use a custom helper:

```
namespace App\Http\Helpers;

class AppHelper
{
   public static function toAlphabet($integer){
    $alphabet =   array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');
    $alpha_flip = array_flip($alphabet);
    if($integer <= 25){
      return $alphabet[$integer];
    }
    elseif($integer > 25){
      $dividend = ($integer + 1);
      $alpha = '';
      $modulo;
      while ($dividend > 0){
        $modulo = ($dividend - 1) % 26;
        $alpha = $alphabet[$modulo] . $alpha;
        $dividend = floor((($dividend - $modulo) / 26));
      } 
      return $alpha;
    }
 }  
}
```

In my config/app.php

I have:

```
'aliases' => [
   'AppHelper' => App\Http\Helpers\AppHelper::class,
];
```

View

```
   <td>
          {{AppHelper::toAlphabet($employee->employee_id)}}
    </td>
```

But when I rendered the view page I got this error:

> Class 'AppHelper' not found

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: is your configuration currently cached? if so clear it ... and this file is `app/Http/Helpers/AppHelper.php` ?

Comment: @lagbox - The error is gone, but I am not getting the desired result.  I want it to display start from A then B and so on. That is

 A

 B

 C ...

But I am getting: 

RC

RD

CH

and so on

Comment: how did the error just disappear? since that is what your question actually is here

Comment: @lagbox - When I cleared the cache

Comment: well then that is the answer to this question ... you can answer it yourself, accept it and make a new question for any other questions you may have that are not exactly this current one ... and don't cache your config while developing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it can be because of many things. there is some hints

1. have you declare it on the autoload
2. did you tried composer update
3. are you sure about your global namespace App
4. do you have the AppHelper on tinker

Good luck